# Trouble displaying correct text from a database based on user's url

Tags: php, html, function

I have a comment box set up on various pages of a website. Since all the comments posted are stored in a common database, I have it send the website each comment is made on using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

The page then displays all comments that match the current page. The problem I'm having is having comments show when there are slight alterations to the url, for example, if the url has #comments at the end of it (I have a shortcut link at the top of the page that scrolls users down to the comments section using an anchor tag like that), it now only displays comments that also have #comments at the end of the url they were created on. Obviously this is a problem since users that scroll down on their own won't have #comments on the end of the page url and then they won't see all the comments.

This is the function I'm using to find the appropriate comments in my database to display:

```
function find_comments() {
    global $connection;

    $query  = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM comments ";
    $query .= "WHERE `page_name` = '".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'";
    $query .= "ORDER BY created DESC";
    $display_comments = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($display_comments);
    return $display_comments;
}
```

So I'm wondering if there is a better way to display the correct comments. I guess I could have a value like a page ID number I specify for each page that will post with the info, but I'd rather have a solution that I don't have to remember to update every time I create a new page that needs a comment box.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways to keep track on the comments, but here's how you could remove the hashes:

```
$url = preg_replace("/#+(.?)*/","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$query .= "WHERE `page_name` = '".$url."'";
```

So remove them both when you save the link and fetch it.

Comment: I tried this and it successfully got rid of the #comment, though it's now not displaying any comments, but I'm not sure why since this logic looks like it should work

Comment: Either you must be passing the variable wrongly to the query, or the match you're expecting has a #comment saved in the db?

Comment: I checked the db and it's successfully saving without #comment. I added in the $url variable in and replaced $query .= "WHERE `page_name` = '".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'";  in my function's code with your $query .= "WHERE `page_name` = '".$url."'";

Comment: try echoing your query and see why the url doesn't match the db

Comment: @coolpup btw, it looks like your query is missing a space before ORDER BY, so maybe it breaks.

Comment: I added in the space, still having problems so I'm checking it out the rest for anything

Comment: Weird, it's working now, but I didn't change anything. I'm not going to question it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What about sending a `source` parameter alongside your comment. Like this:

```
http://domain.com/comment/post?source=site1.com
```

Or even in the POST data.

That way you control what you receive! Only caveat is that you need to modify all websites where your comment box is on, but it's much cleaner.